# How to prevent a delay when playing sounds in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, audio

I need sounds to be played immediately, is there any this can be done?

Comment: what code do you use to play sound?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the prefetch() function of the Player first. After that when you call the start(), it will immediately start the playing. Probably you have to call the prefetch() during splash screen (maybe in a different Thread) or somewhere before you would like to use the player.

Comment: Well, we're talking about a game, which means I have dozens of different sound files. There wouldn't be enough resources to load them all and just keep them.